# PostgreSQL hstore column with LIKE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have a test database where I have a table `example` with a column `attributes` of type `hstore`:

row1: `weight=>'115', height=>'165'` 
row2: `problem=>'weight'`

So, *weight* can be either key or value.

I want to have select statement that when I say `like %weight%`, I get all records which contain weight. Row1 and row2, no matter it is key or value. It should be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE attributes like %weight%
```

How can I do this with the hstore type?

Comment: did you try `WHERE attributes::text like '%weight%'`?..

Comment: thank you very much, that is what i need!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is, is using an `or` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE attributes ? 'weight' -- contains the key
  or 'weight' = any (avals(atributes)) -- is 'weight' contained in any value
```

Another option could be to use the `hstore_to_array()` function to convert the hstore into an array that contains both values and keys:

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE 'weight' = any (hstore_to_array(attributes))
```